# How to define access to just the System event log on Windows 2008 Server

Tags: windows, batch, windows-registry, batch-file, windows-server-2012

I want to restrict administrator user access to the Security event log, is there a way to do it? I was following [this article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/janelewis/archive/2010/04/30/giving-non-administrators-permission-to-read-event-logs-windows-2003-and-windows-2008.aspx), but so far no luck.

Comment: What do you mean by "logging any security event" exactly?  You don't want their actions to show in the Security Event Log?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was I don't want the current user to receive any security event logs in the Event Viewer.

Comment: "I don't want the current user to receive any security event logs" - Still not sure what you mean.  How are they "receiving" security events currently?

Comment: I mean how do I define access to just the System event log on Windows 2012 Server.

Comment: Ok, so you want a user to be able to access the System event log, but not the Security event log?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Sorry for the bad description.

Comment: Ok, can you do us all a favor (including yourself) and _Edit your question_ to reflect what it is you are actually looking for? As-is it doesn't make much sense.  Also include if the user is an administrator or not.

Comment: From MS: [Event Logging Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363658(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I think I can do it using [SDDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379570.aspx).

Comment: Ok cool you edited it, now note: _Standard non-admin users can't view the Security log by default_.  So I'm not sure why you're trying to accomplish this, as they shouldn't be able to get at it in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, I mean restrict administrators access to view Security Log.

Comment: No then. You can't restrict an administrator from anything, as they can just give themselves needed permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You could try by removing the users' [SE_SECURITY_NAME privilege](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363658(v=vs.85).aspx) ([some info on how](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379321(v=vs.85).aspx)), which is the privledge that allows reading and clearing the Security Event Log.

But in reality, you can't restrict an administrator user from anything, as they can just give themselves needed permissions to access it.